# Pandas: For a data frame with multiple columns of integers and strings is there a way to specify which column the max() function looks at?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

The Dataframe:

Image of 21 rows from the Dataframe:

[image: Image of 21 rows from the Dataframe]

When I group by CountryA and Country B and use max(), it looks for the max in the Year column giving me:

Code used:

```py
maxMonth = countryUnits.groupby(['CountryA','CountryB']).max()
print(maxMonth)
```

Image of 7 rows of the current output

[image: Image of 7 rows of the current output]

What would I need to do to get it to look for max in the Units column, giving me this?:

Image of 7 rows of the desired output

[image: Image of 7 rows of the desired output]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC, you can sort by `Units` and take the last (=max) value of each group:

```
maxMonth = (countryUnits.sort_values(by='Units')
                        .groupby(['CountryA','CountryB'], as_index=False)
                        .last()
           )
```

This alternative might actually be faster:

```
maxMonth = (countryUnits.loc[countryUnits.groupby(['CountryA','CountryB'])
                                         ['Units'].idxmax()
                            ])
```

*NB. I can't provide an output as you did not give the input as text*

Comment: Awesome, thank you very much - your response inadvertently taught me about idxmax() too, so a double win! I don't have enough reputation points to upvote (yet) - but I'll circle back when I do

Answer (score 0):

try using idxmax and select by loc:

```
df.loc[df.groupby(['CountryA','CountryB'])['Units'].idxmax()]
```

Comment: This is already one of the possibilities that I have provided  ;)

Comment: Awesome, thank you very much! I don't have enough reputation points to upvote (yet) - but I'll circle back when I do

Comment: No worries mate. Glad it helped.